# the callback of the 'data' event is not invoked,why?

Tags: node.js

i use socket to simulate http request.
here is my program

```
 var request = [
'GET / HTTP/1.1',
'Host: www.baidu.com',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4',
'Cookie: BAIDUID=44BE959D153BFDD6BE362FAE150DF9BF:FG=1; H_PS_TIPFLAG=O; H_PS_TIPCOUNT=1; BD_CK_SAM=1; BDSVRTM=19; H_PS_PSSID=1439_5224_5849_5900_4759_5857_5919'
].join('\r\n');
request += '\r\n';

var net = require('net');

var client = net.connect({
    port: 80,
    host: 'www.baidu.com'
}, function() {
    console.log('client connected');
    client.write(request);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    client.end();
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

but the callback of the 'data' event is not invoked, why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.join` doesn't add an additional `\r\n` at the end.  You need *two* of those to separate the header and body:

```
request += '\r\n\r\n';
```